# jq - error when merging two JSON files "cannot be multiplied"

Tags: json, jq

I have two files containing some JSON.

File1 - some values can be a string, some might be null, VolumeId is always set.

```
[
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx1",
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "Tag2Value",
    "Tag3": "Tag3Value",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "Tag5Value",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx2",
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx3",
    "Tag1": "null",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "null",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "null"
  }
]
```

File2 - VolumeId will always match as those in File1, and Tag7 may or may not be null.

```
[
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx1",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx2",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx3",
    "Tag7": "null"
  }
]
```

I need to combine these into one JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx1",
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "Tag2Value",
    "Tag3": "Tag3Value",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "Tag5Value",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx2",
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxx3",
    "Tag1": "null",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "null",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "null",
    "Tag7": "null"
  }
]
```

I get an error when trying to use the below command:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
array ([{"VolumeId...) and array ([{"VolumeId...) cannot be multiplied
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to merge all entries that have the same `.VolumeId` into one. To do so, first we `flatten` the array of arrays of objects into an array of objects. Then, we `group_by(.VolumeId)`. Finally, we `map` over each group and `reduce` it by calculating the product of all its elements. The final results looks like this:

```
jq -s 'flatten | group_by(.VolumeId) | map(reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x))' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

Answer (score -1):

What you should rather do:

**File1**

```
{
  "vol-xxxxxxx1": {
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "Tag2Value",
    "Tag3": "Tag3Value",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "Tag5Value",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx2": {
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx3": {
    "Tag1": "null",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "null",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "null"
  }
}
```

**File2**

```
{
  "vol-xxxxxxx1": {
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx2": {
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx3": {
    "Tag7": "null"
  }
}
```

Now the command

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

gives the following:

```
{
  "vol-xxxxxxx1": {
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "Tag2Value",
    "Tag3": "Tag3Value",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "Tag5Value",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx2": {
    "Tag1": "Tag1Value",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "Tag4Value",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "Tag6Value",
    "Tag7": "Tag7Value"
  },
  "vol-xxxxxxx3": {
    "Tag1": "null",
    "Tag2": "null",
    "Tag3": "null",
    "Tag4": "null",
    "Tag5": "null",
    "Tag6": "null",
    "Tag7": "null"
  }
}
```