# How to merge arrays from two files into one array with jq?

Tags: json, join, jq

I would like to merge two files containing JSON. They each contain an array of JSON objects.

registration.json

```
[
    { "name": "User1", "registration": "2009-04-18T21:55:40Z" },
    { "name": "User2", "registration": "2010-11-17T15:09:43Z" }
]
```

useredits.json

```
[
    { "name": "User1", "editcount": 164 },
    { "name": "User2", "editcount": 150 },
    { "name": "User3", "editcount": 10 }
]
```

In the ideal scenario, I would like to have the following as a result of the merge operation:

```
[
    { "name": "User1", "editcount": 164, "registration": "2009-04-18T21:55:40Z" },
    { "name": "User2", "editcount": 150, "registration": "2010-11-17T15:09:43Z" }
]
```

I have found https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1247#issuecomment-348817802 but I get

```
jq: error: module not found: jq
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.name)[] 
          | select(length > 1) | add ]' registration.json useredits.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "User1",
    "registration": "2009-04-18T21:55:40Z",
    "editcount": 164
  },
  {
    "name": "User2",
    "registration": "2010-11-17T15:09:43Z",
    "editcount": 150
  }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Although not strictly answering the question, the command below

```
jq -s 'flatten | group_by(.name) | map(reduce .[] as $x ({}; . * $x))'
      registration.json useredits.json
```

generates this output:

```
[
    { "name": "User1", "editcount": 164, "registration": "2009-04-18T21:55:40Z" },
    { "name": "User2", "editcount": 150, "registration": "2010-11-17T15:09:43Z" },
    { "name": "User3", "editcount": 10 }
]
```

Source:
[jq - error when merging two JSON files "cannot be multiplied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880891/jq-error-when-merging-two-json-files-cannot-be-multiplied)

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes you have jq 1.5 or later, and that:

- joins.jq as shown below is in the directory ~/.jq/ or the directory ~/.jq/joins/
- there is no file named joins.jq in the pwd
- registration.json has been fixed to make it valid JSON (btw, this can be done by jq itself).

The invocation to use would then be:

```
jq -s 'include "joins"; joins(.name)' registration.json useredits.json
```

#### joins.jq

```
# joins.jq Version 1 (12-12-2017)

def distinct(s):
  reduce s as $x ({}; .[$x | (type[0:1] + tostring)] = $x)
  |.[];

# Relational Join
# joins/6 provides similar functionality to the SQL INNER JOIN statement:
#   SELECT (Table1|p1), (Table2|p2)
#     FROM Table1
#     INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1|filter1) = (Table2|filter2)
# where filter1, filter2, p1 and p2 are filters.

# joins(s1; s2; filter1; filter2; p1; p2)
# s1 and s2 are streams of objects corresponding to rows in Table1 and Table2;
# filter1 and filter2 determine the join criteria;
# p1 and p2 are filters determining the final results.
# Input: ignored
# Output: a stream of distinct pairs [p1, p2]
# Note: items in s1 for which filter1 == null are ignored, otherwise all rows are considered.
#
def joins(s1; s2; filter1; filter2; p1; p2):
  def it: type[0:1] + tostring;
  def ix(s;f):
    reduce s as $x ({};  ($x|f) as $y | if $y == null then . else .[$y|it] += [$x] end);
  # combine two dictionaries using the cartesian product of distinct elements
  def merge:
    .[0] as $d1 | .[1] as $d2
    | ($d1|keys_unsorted[]) as $k
    | if $d2[$k] then distinct($d1[$k][]|p1) as $a | distinct($d2[$k][]|p2) as $b | [$a,$b]
      else empty end;

   [ix(s1; filter1), ix(s2; filter2)] | merge;

def joins(s1; s2; filter1; filter2):
  joins(s1; s2; filter1; filter2; .; .) | add ;

# Input: an array of two arrays of objects
# Output: a stream of the joined objects
def joins(filter1; filter2):
  joins(.[0][]; .[1][]; filter1; filter2);

# Input: an array of arrays of objects.
# Output: a stream of the joined objects where f defines the join criterion.
def joins(f):
  # j/0 is defined so TCO is applicable
  def j:
    if length < 2 then .[][]
    else [[ joins(.[0][]; .[1][]; f; f)]] + .[2:] | j
    end;
   j ;
```

Comment: In order to be more portable and more readable, I've opted to use the answer by RomanPerekhrest. Thanks for answering my question though!